# D3.js delete node on contextmenu click

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to delete a D3 node once i right click on it. I have tried the below code but nothing is happening. Please assist on how to do it.

```
        var menu = [
        {
         title: 'Remove Node',
         action: function(elm, d, i) {

        if (d.parent) {

          // find child and remove it
          for (var ii = 0; ii < d.parent.children.length; ii++) {
            if (d.parent.children[ii].name === d.name) {
              d.parent.children.splice(ii, 1);
              break;
            }
          }
        }


      d3.select(this).selectAll(d).remove(); 

    }
}
];
```

Comment: Hmm, why not try something like `on('contextmenu', function(d, i){/*remove with index here*/})` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13090321/custom-context-menu-in-d3-and-svg

Comment: is it not the same thing as the one i am doing?